# OpenJDK Java 8 - When will it be made available in Trusty 14.04.x

Tags: 14.04, openjdk

It appears that OpenJDK Java 8 has been out for a while now.  However, it is not available in the "Ubuntu 14.04.x" (and derivatives) via the repositories. When, if ever, while Java 8 become available.

Comment: I think [this](http://openjdk.java.net/install/) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue on launchpad for backporting `openjdk-8` to 14.04 : [#1368094](https://bugs.launchpad.net/trusty-backports/+bug/1368094)

But if you really need it right now, you can use [openjdk-r's ppa](https://launchpad.net/~openjdk-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install openjdk-8
```

Comment: The "link" to openjdk.net is of no use right now since openjdk-8 is not available in the Ubuntu repository.  I do not want to add the PPA at this time.  So I consider this issue closed.